# diff & patch tools for Windows that support UCS-2 encoded text files

Tags: windows, diff

I'm looking for a pair of `diff`- and `patch`-like tool(s) that can understand various **text** file encodings, especially UTF-8 and UCS-2.

Currently I have to write a custom bashscript (in Cygwin) that converts the files back-and-forth between UTF-8 and UCS-2 to perform diff's and patch's via temp files, but this is of course suboptimal because it needs installation of Cygwin.

Preferably the tool should have a GUI, but even a CLI-only tool will be welcome.

The tool will be used for game modding, to patch .ini files which, after some investigations, were apparently *required* (by the game) to be encoded using UCS-2 (game fails spectacularly if the .ini files are converted to UTF-8 permanently -- can't do anything about that).

Comment: You can get Windows versions of `diff` and `patch` that do not have Cygwin dependencies, and you could script them with PowerShell (or possibly `cmd`) instead of `bash`.